# Неблокировка при активном состоянии

Tags: ios, xcode, iphone, apple

Как сделать чтобы при открытом приложении телефон не блокировался?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы не блокировался вообще, в appDelegate напишите

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = YES;
```

Либо тот же код, где то в приложении, если надо отключать блокировку не навсегда, а при каких то обстоятельствах